# javascript string method

Tags: javascript

hi i want to a one line of code (without using loop) in javascript to find the if there is semicolon in a string... please help if any one knows

Answer (score 10):

```
myStringVal.indexOf(";") !== -1;
```

<sub>For more information, check out the documentation for `String.prototype.indexOf()`.</sub>

Comment: +1 (although I always advocate `>= 0` rather than `!= -1` out of paranoia; but the spec does specifically say `-1` for not found, so...) But **please** refer people to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). w3schools is incomplete at best.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (stringvalue.indexOf(";") >= 0) {
    alert("String value contains semi colon");
}
```